# wp shortcode breaks get_post_thumbnail

Tags: shortcode

I'm having some trouble with short code's breaking a featured image I have set on my home page in Wordpress (4.0). For some reason, when I paste in my shortcode in the wp-admin > page > edit > content for the home page, suddenly my featured image stops working. It's working until I paste in the shortcode and update the page, but then the image disappears and the_post_thumbnail() returns false. I've also tried get_the_post_thumbnail() without success.

Here's my code excerpt from "front-page.php":

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {the_post_thumbnail();} ?>
</div>
```

And here's the shortcode function from "functions.php":

```
// [random_testimonial]
function short_code_get_random_testimonial(){
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonial', 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'orderby' => 'rand' );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
      $random_testimonial = get_the_content();
      $author = get_the_title();
      $rt  = '<p class="quote">' . $random_testimonial;
      $rt .= '</p><p class="right">&ndash; ' . $author . '</p>';
    endwhile;
    return $rt;
}

// Register the shortcodes.
add_shortcode( 'random_testimonial', 'short_code_get_random_testimonial' );

// Allow text widgets to contain shortcodes.
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('the_content', 'do_shortcode');
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have solved this one. It seems to have something to do with the fact that I was calling a custom post type with the shortcode, so by the time the_post_thumbnail() was called, the query had changed to refer to the custom post type included in the shortcode ("testimonial") rather than the parent post (in this case the home page). I revised my code as follows to catch the image before the shortcode is called, and all is working again:

```
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php 
            // go ahead and get the post image in case [random_testimonial]
            // shortcode is used in page content which will break the query.
            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {$image = get_the_post_thumbnail();} ?>

        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
<div class="small-12 medium-6 columns">
    <?php
        // Echo post image from above.
        if(isset($image)){echo $image;}
    ?>
</div>
```